# Editing websites locally

Tags: html, css, browser, stylesheet

I think I read somewhere that you can edit the stylesheet of other websites locally on your computer. For example I'd like to edit the stylesheet of Facebook just for my own view. How can I do that? Is there anyway I can edit the original stylesheet CSS and tell my browser to read one locally instead of the original one?

Comment: Do you want your browser to read systematically your local CSS each time the website is visited ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) extension for Chrome to apply custom CSS rules to specific websites. It has a great UI you can use to alter bits of the page without actually having to write CSS. You can write raw CSS if you want to though.

For example, I use it to hide the `<div>` containing comments on YouTube, so I never have to see pointless arguments between morons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firebug plugin for Firefox. That allows you to edit the styles as you see them. Such a valuable development tool, I couldn't recommend it highly enough. I use it every day and no doubt other developers do too.

Google Chrome/Safari also has a great web development tool which offers similar features.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants the changes to persist.

Comment: Perhaps this should be stated in the question then? I see someone has already asked him the question in his OP.

Answer (score 1):

Either you do something browser specific (e.g. for [Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/usercss/)) or you use a proxy server that lets you rewrite requests that match a specific pattern (e.g. [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)).

Comment: @Charliepiga — Any which let you specify a proxy server (which is almost anything until you get into the "Browser built into a TV" sort of area).

Answer (score 0):

Firebug will do that nicely for you.

Here is a link for you to download to firefox.

http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers allow you to write your own stylesheet but they are browser specific and I don't know if FF is included in them.  However I do know that you can setup preferences in firefox.  Below is a link on how to use your own stylesheet for Opera and IE

http://blackwidows.co.uk/clients/imp-guide/accessify/local-style.php